# Figuring out how to write a logistic regression model in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I am trying to write a model in sklearn for. I have the training set with xtrain of dimension (num_samples,65000,2) and ytrain of dimension(num_samples).

I'm using

```
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs',
                          multi_class='multinomial').fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

But getting an error :

> Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Can anyone please suggest how I might fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Input data shape has to be 2D or 1D for a logistic regression model to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you are passing a 3d array whereas you should have pass in a 2d array.

Maybe if we could see what your data looks like we could help you more.

This should resolve your error :

```
samples, x, y = xtrain.shape
new_dataset = xtrain.reshape((samples,x*y))
```

Then fit again on the new dataset